# Finding $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty {{1} \over ({2n-1})^2} $ given $ \sum_{n=1} ^ \infty {{1} \over {n^2}} = {{\pi^2}\over {6}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> If $$ \sum_{n=1} ^ \infty  {{1} \over {n^2}} = {{\pi^2}\over {6}},$$ find $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty {{1} \over ({{2n-1}})^2}. $$

I tried an approach using partial fractions and tried to transform ${{1} \over ({{2n-1}})^2} $ into something in terms of $ {{1} \over {n^2}}$ , but so far I haven't had any luck.

Is there some other approach I can use?

Comment: I believe that your $i$’s should all be $1$, not $i$.

Comment: and $\pi^2/6$, not $\pi/6$.

Comment: @Jonathan , yes it is indeed pi^2/6, also the summation is over n and not k.

Comment: See also: [How can we show $\frac{\pi^2}{8} = 1 + \frac1{3^2} +\frac1{5^2} + \frac1{7^2} + …$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1454960)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HINT: $$\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi^2}6&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^2}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{(2n-1)^2}+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{(2n)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{(2n-1)^2}+\frac14\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^2}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 7):

Hint: consider $$\sum_1^{\infty}{1\over(2n)^2}$$

Answer (score 6):

$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You could try to find $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^2}$ and then decompose a partial sum of $\sum_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2}$ into odd and even numbers and take the limit. By the way $$\sum_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/6$$